# How can I specify a customized value for the Jcrop 'setSelect' option?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I'm having trouble understanding the Jcrop 'setSelect' option. On the jCrop website it lists an example as

```
setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]
```

which in general they refer to as

```
setSelect:   [ x, y, x2, y2 ]
```

Now, mathematically, I assume this means the coordinates of the lower left corner, and upper right corner of the image. That is, (x,y) and (x2,y2) are the coordinates. But the example they give seems to indicate that it is the upper right corner, and lower left corner, respectively. That seems weird. Anyway, I am trying to generalize the setSelect feature, since I may not know the exact dimensions of the photo that will be 'jCropped'. Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
setSelect:   [ $('#cropbox').width()/4,
               $('#cropbox').height()/4,
               ($('#cropbox').width()/4)*3,
               ($('#cropbox').height()/4)*3]
```

Nothing is selected when I use this code. However, when I use the example code `setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]`, then it works. But I don't want to use this, because I won't know the actual dimension of the photo being cropped. Why doesn't my code work?

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at this Jcrop thingy. It looks like when it calculates those values, it expects them to be `Math.round()`ed, so to speak. [I've put together a jsFiddle showing the core of what needs to be done](http://jsfiddle.net/kLbVM/3/).

Also, here's the code ->

**the jQuery** ->

```
var jcrop_api;
jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox');
function getDimensions(){
  return [
    Math.round($('#cropbox').width() / 2),
    Math.round($('#cropbox').height()/2),
    Math.round($('#cropbox').width()/ 4),
    Math.round($('#cropbox').height()/4)
  ];
}
$(function(){
  $('#setSelect').click(function(){
    jcrop_api.setSelect(getDimensions());
  });      
});
```

**the HTML structure** ->

```
<div id="cropbox">
   <img src="http://media.giantbomb.com/uploads/2/27962/1867070-illionois_state_bird_and_flower.jpg" />     
</div><br/>
<button id="setSelect"> Set Select </button>
```

Make sure you include the relevant JS and CSS files for this plugin, and all should be working out of the box.